# How does pairwise independence restrict dependence to a third variable?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables such that

- $X,Y,Z$ have mean $0$ and variance $1$.
- $X$ and $Y$ are pairwise independent.
- $Z$ can be arbitrarily dependent on $X$ and $Y$.

My question is: **What can we say about the dependence of $Z$ on $X$ and $Y$?** For example, if $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Z)=1$ (so they are perfectly correlated), then $Z$ and $Y$ must be independent. **In general, can we say anything about how much $Z$ can depend on (or be correlated with) $X$ and $Y$?** Maybe something like $|\operatorname{Cov}(X,Z)+\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z)|\leq 1$ holds?

Comment: Are you sure that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent if $Cov(X,Z) = 1$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka: $\textrm{Cov}(X,Z)=EXZ=1=(EX^2EZ^2)^{1/2}$. Equality in Cauchy-Schwarz implies that $X=aZ$ (and then in fact $X=Z$ from the other conditions).

Comment: If you type `3\text{Cov}(X,Y)`, the result will be different from that of `3\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)`, thus $3\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ versus $3\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y).$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I've changed \text to \operatorname.

Comment: Bessel's inequality gives $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)^2 + \mathrm{Cov}(Y,Z)^2 \leq \mathrm{Var}(Z) = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is is hopeless, as becomes clear when you write
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Z)+\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z)=E(X+Y)Z . \tag{1}\label{463874_1}
$$
Your assumptions don't restrict $U=X+Y$ much, you only know that $EU=0$, $\operatorname{Var}(U)=2$ and $U$ is [2-divisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)).

More to the point perhaps, you can just take $Z=(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ to obtain a counterexample, then \eqref{463874_1} equals $\sqrt{2}$. This is also the largest possible value, by Cauchy–Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you! I agree this is as much as you can say when it comes to the sum of covariances.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X,Y$ by i.i.d. with $\Pr(X=+1) = \Pr(X=-1) = 1/2,$ and let $Z=XY.$ Then $Z$ has the same distribution as $X$ or $Y,$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ and $Z$ are independent and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, and all three have the same distribution, but $X,Y,Z$ are not independent.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this example before and the fact that pairwise independence does not imply joint independence.